# Android navigation component side navigation just on specific fragment

Tags: java, android

How can I use side navigation (DrawerLayout + NavigationView) just on *main_fragment* and *profile_fragment*? *login_fragment* should be without DrawerLayout and NavigationView, just Toolbar and content.

Navigation graph:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the drawer in your activity and than handle it's visibility in `addOnDestinationChangedListener` :

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if (destination.id == R.id.someFragment) {
                toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
                drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
            } else {
                toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
            }
        }
```

Don't do this in fragments, it's not a good pattern not that it doesn't compile or something.